# Jquery add value into select syntax right after this dropdown menu is loaded from another page

Tags: jquery, select, load, onchange

I have the following code that loads element from a remote page (under same domain) into the current page. The element #Beijing contains a dropdown menu, and I wish to add some value into the menu in select syntax after it is loaded. The value I would like to add is:

**onChange="this.form['CAT_Custom_221342'].value=this[this.selectedIndex].value"**

and here is the code I've got, please help me to edit it furthur, thank you.

```
function StateBeijingNext() { 
$('#SuburbSelect').load('/Country/CN/_CN_suburbs.html #Beijing');   
}
```

Comment: Without seeing your html we can't be sure what exactly you require. Is `#Beijing` actually the `<select>` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to insert javascript event handlers into your html; this is difficult to follow logically when debugging, and is simply poor style, since you don't have a clean separation of content and functionality. Since you are using jQuery, leverage its event binding capabilities:

```
$('#SuburbSelect').on('change', '#Beijing', function() {
    this.form['CAT_Custom_221342'].value = this[this.selectedIndex].value;
});
```

You can bind this event handler as soon as **the DOM is ready**, and when your new content is inserted the change handler will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks nbrooks, I think I need your very first code since I need to keep this part for a reason, could you please please sent me the first version of your answer? Thanks

Comment: @wanghaipeng Sorry I'm not sure what you mean, I don't think I changed anything...what exactly do you need to keep the same? Oh if you mean the additional function wrapper on the outside, that's just a [dom ready function](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) which tells the browser not to run this until the dom is ready. If you already have one, just drop my inner code directly into yours.

Answer (score 1):

`.load()` accepts a callback function that allows you access to the elements you're loading after they're been loaded, see below:

```
function StateBeijingNext() { 
    $('#SuburbSelect').load('/Country/CN/_CN_suburbs.html #Beijing', function(){
      //the element has been successfully loaded into the DOM.
      //peform your custom logic against the #Beijing element here.
    });   
}
```